# Loading Python Virtualenv files created using PyCharm using command line

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, virtualenv

I created a new project in PyCharm and I made an environment file for the project. I want to use Jupyter Notebook with that project now and since Jupyter in PyCharm is not as great, I want to launch it from `cmd`. I am not able to figure out to activate the environment created in PyCharm from the command line. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- find the location of environment from PyCharm's project's interpreter settings
- From the terminal Run:

  ```
  source /path/to/env-activate
  ```

Comment: I located the path for the environment. But when I run `source path-to-env` in `cmd`, I get an error which says `'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I think I got it. I took a different approach. I found the `activate.bat`. I then dragged and dropped it in `cmd` and hit `Enter`. This worked and the environment changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution For Linux**

try to use **pyenv**, once you install virtualenv with pyenv for example

```
cd ~/your_project_root_folder
pyenv install 3.6.1
pyenv virtualenv 3.6.1 your_venv_name
pyenv local your_venv_name
```

Then whatever shell command is launched (even from pyenv) you will have correct virtualenv and you don't need to change anything inside pycharm

#### PyENV

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer